# how to pass the data back from table view cell to table view class?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In this i had three sections in which i need last section tableviewcell data needs to pass to the table view class and another one in the first section i am having radio button whenever it got enabled then only the third section needs to be shown on table view if not it should be hided

Table view class

```
    let url = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bMlqRPbjGW?indent=2"
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVWKKHtWbm?indent=2"
    var shippingArray :[[String: AnyObject]] = []
    var keys = [String]()
    let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
    var arrayss =  [String:AnyObject]()
    var checkIsRadioSelect = [Int]()
    var checkIsButtonEnable = [Int]()
    var checkIsPaymentRadioSelect = [Int]()
    let response : [Int] = []
    var chekIndex:IndexPath?
    var selected: Bool = true
    var dataArray :[Any] = []
    var A: [Any] = []
    var B: [Any] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        tableDetails.isHidden = true
        continueButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        myActivityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 130, y: 320, width: 30, height: 30)
        myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
        myActivityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myActivityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
        self.shippingaddressURL()
        tableDetails.delegate = self
        tableDetails.dataSource = self
        tableDetails.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        tableDetails.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableDetails.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        self.title = "Checkout"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
      func shippingaddressURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            self.shippingArray = (jsonObj!.value(forKey: "address") as? [[String: AnyObject]])!
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    @IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
                self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 3
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if (section == 0){
            return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
        }
        else if (section == 2){
            return "SHIPPING METHOD"
        }
        else{
            return ""
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            return 62
        }
        else {
            return 282
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }

    @IBAction func newAddressAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newAddress") as! NewAddressViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addtoCartVC, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0){
            return shippingArray.count
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
    }
    @IBAction func continueButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if selected == false{
            let radiobutton = SCLAlertView()
            _ =  radiobutton.showError("Warning", subTitle: "Please select shipping method", closeButtonTitle: "OK")

        }else{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let addtoCartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "payment") as! PaymentMethodViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addtoCartVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        shippingArray.remove(at:sender.tag)
        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
            tableDetails.isHidden = false
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
            cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
            let mobilenumber : Any =  arr["number"] as AnyObject
            cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\(mobilenumber)"
            cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
                cell.editButton.isHidden = false
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            }else
            {
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                cell.editButton.isHidden = true
                cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            }
            return cell
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addresscell", for: indexPath) as! CreateNewAddressTableViewCell
            cell.newAddressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newAddressAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingmethodcell", for: indexPath) as! MethodTableViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }
```

table view cell class

```
   var chekIndex:IndexPath?
    var arrayss =  [String:AnyObject]()
    var keys = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVgbyVQGmq?indent=2"

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.shippingmethodURL()
        shippingTableView.delegate = self
        shippingTableView.dataSource = self
        shippingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        shippingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = shippingTableView.rowHeight
        // Initialization code
    }
    @IBAction func paymentRadioAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        _ = sender.center
        let centralPoint = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            isSelected = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func shippingmethodURL() {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(self.arrayss)
                self.keys = jsonObj?.allKeys as! [String]
                print(self.keys)
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
                    let sectionHeight = self.arrayss.count * 31
                    let cellHeight = self.keys.count * 44
                    self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(sectionHeight + cellHeight)
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return arrayss.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.keys[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.tintColor = UIColor.white
        header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 17)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        let key = self.keys[section]
        let a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        return a.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
        let key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
        let name = dictionary["name"]
        let price = dictionary ["price"]
        cell.methodLabel.text = name  as? String
        cell.priceLabel.text = price as? String
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paymentRadioAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        if chekIndex == indexPath {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
        }
        return cell
    }
```

and the layout for this is as shown here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var addressSelected : Bool = false

@IBAction func selectRadioButton(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
    let chekIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
    _ = self.checkIsButtonEnable.index(of: sender.tag)
    tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
    if sender.isSelected {

    } else{
        if(chekIndex == nil){
            self.checkIsRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.checkIsRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
            self.checkIsButtonEnable.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.checkIsButtonEnable.append(sender.tag)
            self.tableDetails.reloadData()
            self.addressSelected = true
            tableDetails.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (addressSelected == false){
            if (section == 0){
                return shippingArray.count
            }
            else if (section == 1) {
                return 1
            }
            else{
                return 0
            }
        }else{
            if (section == 0)
            {
                return shippingArray.count
            }
            else
            {
                return 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to pass data from table view cell to table view class also needed ?